# C# Windows Forms app - Clear ComboBox selected text from another ComboBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

Windows Forms application (c#).
I have two ComboBoxes. 
If I select an item in one, I want the text in the other one to be blank.

This is what I have:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ComboBox2.Text = "";
}

private void ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ComboBox1.Text = "";
}
```

... but as you can see, when I make a selection in one, the text in both ComboBoxes get cleared.

How to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't actually get this behavior.  First of all, `.Text` is separate from `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex`.  It just represents the text literally inputted by a user that may or may not exist in the list of drop down values.  Setting this property programmatically does not actually fire the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.  It also has no effect on the value selected in the `ComboBox` if the value has been selected from one of the choices in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [ComboBox.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) to -1

> A zero-based index of the currently selected item. A value of negative
>   one (-1) is returned if no item is selected.

or rather based on your specifications try something lie

```
    private bool changed = false;
    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!changed)
        {
            changed = true;
            ComboBox2.Text = "";
            changed = false;
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!changed)
        {
            changed = true; 
            ComboBox1.Text = "";
            changed = false;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: This still clears both ComboBoxes. I want the item of the current ComboBox to stay selected.